# Does anyone know how to use the 'Create Space Time Cube' tool in Arcmap? it gives me an error and I don't understand why

Tags: spatial, arcgis, analysis, arcmap, hotspot

I have point data at municipal level and am looking for information on how the input data should be structured to create a spatio-temporal cube of available data to visualise and analyse emerging hotspots.I need to find out if there is an error in the organisation of the input file.